# Adding class active to nav-tabs li on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating one long page with a navbar using bootstrap nav-tabs, clicking on the nav-tabs opens their respective sub navbar (tab-content), the nav-content anchors then directs you to a certain position of the page and adds the class 'active'. Upon scroll the class active is also added to show the current position on the page.

My problem is when I reach the tab-content of the next nav-tab, the nav-tab li should become active and show its tab-content just like when I physically click the tab. How do I make the li of the nav-tabs active upon scroll?

To show my problem I have made a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Felirou/qLwcm15a/14/

As you can see, when scrolling the page, the respective anchors in the submenu (tab-content) becomes active using the jQuery below. However when reaching the orange / purple color the nav tab doesn't become active, but when you click it you can see that its content has become active.

```
<!-- the navbar -->
<div class="row" id="navbar">  
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id="navbarPresentation" class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Green/Blue</a></li>
    <li id="navbarIntroduction"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Orange/Purple</a>
 </ul>

<!-- This is the sub-menu of the header, the tab-content -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <nav class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#green"><h5>green</h5></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#blue"><h5>blue</h5></a>
    </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <nav class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#orange"><h5>orange</h5></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#purple"><h5>purple</h5></a>
    </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


// onScroll event for the sub nav also called the tab-content
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
  function onScroll(event){
      var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.tab-content a').each(function () {
      var currLink = $(this);
      var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('.tab-content a').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
}
```

I have tried a lot of different things so I'm not sure which failed attempt to post. But I imagine I have to do something with parent() or some boolean true/false to add a class to the li, but I just can't seem to make it work. Can someone help me or point me in the right direction?

In advance, thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please post the html too. For future question please pay attention to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit and added a jsfiddle, will that do for the html requested? :-)

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to do this :

```
let tabs = $('.tab-content a');
tabs.each(function(){
let self = this;

$(this).on('click',function(){
  removeActiveClass();
  $(self).addClass('active'); 
 });
});
function removeActiveClass(){
 tabs.each(function(){
  $(this).removeClass('active');
 });
}
```

you have to make loop on the selected array of ('.tab-content a') now it will only highlight the active link only Hope this help .

check -> [codepen link](https://codepen.io/andrew-basilioos/pen/KvvYEq?editors=1111)

Comment: Thank you for so fast response. Hm I think maybe I didn't explain my question so well. I made a jsfiddle maybe you can see what I mean from that. It's not so clean but hopefully you will see what I mean when scrolling the document. https://jsfiddle.net/Felirou/qLwcm15a/4/

Comment: now check it again is that what u want https://jsfiddle.net/qLwcm15a/6/

Comment: I removed some of the stuff not necessary, the link I just clicked nothing happened when I scrolled. The link I provided the tab-content a becomes active upon scroll, but I want their respective li nav-tabs to become active when reached

Comment: add this class to ur css : `li.active a{
  color:yellow !important;
  background-color:black !important;
}` now the main nav bar tabs will change their style when u click on them

Comment: Adding that to your fiddle it still doesn't change the classes in the navbar during scrolling, at least not for me? I'm sorry my post was a little clumsy in the beginning. I also provided a new jsfiddle in the OP, if you could take a new look at that? Thank you so much btw :-)